# I have XP on one partition and Windows 7 on another. How do I install Ubuntu on a separate partition?

Tags: system-installation

I have a 500 GB HDD. There are 6 partitions. Windows XP is installed on partition C. Windows 7 is installed on partition D. I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on partition E. Please tell me how to do that---- step by step.

Comment: you using windows XP poses a threat to you, your family and your whole nation, wherever you live (potentially). realistically it might not be that bad but your pc could very well be used as the ground zero for a grand-scale hack by a foreign hacking group. don't use XP, most importantly don't connect it to the internet. Microsoft has made many statements to that end : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14223/windows-xp-end-of-support

Answer (score 1):

during installation you will be asked what partition to install onto.

assuming that all partitions are formatted with some filesystem, i suggest you delete the filesystem from windows partition E (numbering works differently under linux). that way it will be marked as free space and it will be easier to select it during installation.